# tab_stat_cpct producing wrong column percentage totals

Tags: r, expss

I have been running tables including tab_stat_cpct hoping to have col %'s appearing in the bottom row adding up to 100% in each column. But this is what I get...

```
mtcars %>%
  tab_cells(am) %>%
  tab_cols(total(),vs) %>%
  tab_stat_cases(label = "N") %>%
  tab_stat_cpct(label="%") %>% 
  tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_rows") %>% drop_rc() %>% 
  split_table_to_df()

1                   #Total vs   
2                           0  1
3 am            0 N     19 12  7
4                 %     59 67 50
5               1 N     13  6  7
6                 %     41 33 50
7    #Total cases N     32 18 14
8                 %     32 18 14
```

They just repeat the total n of cases in each column, not the %. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label` argument is just a label for current block. By default all totals are unweighted number of cases and don't depend on `label`.   To get desired results we need to set total statistics and total labels:

```
library(expss)
mtcars %>%
    tab_cells(am) %>%
    tab_cols(total(),vs) %>%
    tab_stat_cases(label = "N", total_label = "") %>%
    tab_stat_cpct(label="%", total_statistic = "w_cpct", total_label = "") %>% 
    tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_rows") 

# |    |    |    | #Total |     vs |     |
# |    |    |    |        |      0 |   1 |
# | -- | -- | -- | ------ | ------ | --- |
# | am |  0 |  N |  19.00 |  12.00 |   7 |
# |    |    |  % |  59.38 |  66.67 |  50 |
# |    |  1 |  N |  13.00 |   6.00 |   7 |
# |    |    |  % |  40.62 |  33.33 |  50 |
# |    |  # |  N |  32.00 |  18.00 |  14 |
# |    |    |  % | 100.00 | 100.00 | 100 |
```